# What do CMPLX, MAT, and VCT mean on the casio fx-85GT plus?

Tags: calculator

On my Casio fx-85GT plus, I noticed at the top of the LCD, next to `STAT`, were `CMPLX`, `MAT`, and `VCT` (I know they are separated like this by looking in diagnostic mode). However, I can't seem to find what they mean in the manual, and haven't ever noticed them on.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what they could mean?

(Sorry if this is the wrong site, I wasn't sure which site to ask it to)

Comment: You mean on the LCD, right?

Comment: Yes. They were between STAT and DRG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex numbers, matrices, and vectors. The 85GT Plus doesn't have these features, but it probably uses the same LCD unit as another model that does have them. This is a common way for a manufacturer to save money by decreasing the number of unique parts that they have to produce and stock.